# How to get object array from session stored with json.stringify?

Tags: json, angular, session-storage

I have a class:

```
export class CartItem {  
  productname!: string;
  quantity!: number;
}
```

I store an array of this in session as:

```
cartItems: Array<CartItem> = [];
...
...
sessionStorage.setItem("CurrentCart", JSON.stringify(this.cartItems));
```

When retrieving this, I tried:

```
this.cartItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("CurrentCart") || '') as Array<CartItem>;
```

But this returns:

```
Cart Items [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

and not the array with values.

From what I see in some examples [Angular convert json to array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288615/angular-convert-json-to-array-of-object), seems I need to map the array back or write a custom transformer https://medium.com/typescript-center/casting-json-objects-to-typescript-classes-a-deep-dive-835b8f8988bf

Is that the only way? Seems inefficient and cumbersome for bigger classes.

Comment: That should not happen and I sincerely doubt it actually happens. However, without a fully working example, it is hard to tell what and where things are going wrong. Please provide a working example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The round trip to JSON just gives you vanilla objects, you can't serialise classes to JSON. So yes if you want to rehydrate class instances you have to have code to do that.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to store and retrieve data in a session without having to parse every single time? We allow users to navigate all over the app and have cart visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse` will not convert some arbitrary json to the `CartItem` class. It will simply convert a json string to json primitives (string, boolean, null, array, object).

You would need to implement some custom encoding/decoding. Example:

```js
class CartItem {
  constructor(public productName: string, public quantity: number){}
  toJson(): any {
    return {productName: this.productName, quantity: this.quantity}
  }
  toString(): string{
    return `CartItem{${this.productName}:${this.quantity}}`
  }
  static fromJson(obj: any): CartItem {
    return new CartItem(obj.productName, obj.quantity)
  }
  static fromJsonList(obj: any): CartItem[] {
    return obj.map(item => CartItem.fromJson(item))
  }
}

class Cart {
  private cartItems: CartItem[] = []
  private static readonly STORE_KEY = "CurrentCart"
  function save(){
    const storedJson = JSON.stringify(this.cartItems.map(item => item.toJson()))
    sessionStorage.setItem(Cart.STORE_KEY, storedJson);
  }
  function load(){
    const storedJson = sessionStorage.getItem(Cart.STORE_KEY) || '[]'
    this.cartItems = CartItem.fromJsonList(JSON.parse(storedJson));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to store and retrieve data in a session without having to parse every single time? We allow users to navigate all over the app and have cart visible.

Comment: @BlahFoo I wouldn't worry about that. The performance hit should be negligible, unless you're doing it hundreds of times a second.